Relative strength of conjugate acids and bases
Q: In our chemistry lesson i.e "Acid-Base equilibria" we have learned  about acid-base conjugate with their strength (based on Bronsted-Lowry acid base pair)
so

if HA (hypothetical acid)  is weak, it's conjugate base  will be stronger than it's source acid i.e HA, again

if HB (hypothetical base) is weak, it's conjugate acid will be much stronger than HB.

if HA is strong, the conjugate base will be weak

if HB is strong, it's conjugate acid will be weak

also $\ce{K_\mathrm{a}}$ & $\ce{K_\mathrm{b}}$ are directly proportional to the strength of acid and base (i.e when the value of $\ce{K_\mathrm{a}}$ & $\ce{K_\mathrm{b}}$ increases acid and base strength also increases)


Based on this as we know $\ce{NH3}$ is weak base and it's conjugate acid must be stronger and must contains higher $\ce{K_\mathrm{b}}$ value. However $\ce{NH3}$ which has $\ce{K_\mathrm{b}}$ value $1.8 \times 10^{-9}$ i.e higher than its conjugate acid i.e $\ce{K_\mathrm{a}}$ value of $0.556\times 10^{-9}$. So even if we use big approximation we get the formula  $\ce{K_\mathrm{b}=10^4 K_\mathrm{a}}$
according to the above definition the value of $\ce{NH4}$ (conjugate acid) must be much larger than it's source base.
Why is this so? According to the above 5 definitions doesn't it contradict?

For plain text formatting by StackExchange markdown, see as inspiration SE meta - formatting // SE meta -  tables  // Less known formatting tips

Guides for formatting of chemical/mathematical formulas/expressions/equations: Basics / Detailed / Upright vs Italics / Math SE Mathjax tutorial
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Abbreviating acids and bases with HA and HB is awkward because the convention is HA and $\ce{A-}$ or $\ce{BH+}$ and B for conjugate acid/base pairs.

It makes more sense to compare the strength of two weak acids than the acid strength of a weak acid with the base strength of its conjugate base.

As soon as we discuss the strength of an acid in quantitative terms, we know that it is a weak acid.

Primary data are values $K_\text{a}\cdot K_\text{b}=K_\text{w}$, where the constants on the left side are the respective acidity/basicity constants of the considered conjugate acid/base pair.
Strong acids/bases have so big values of $K_\text{a}$ resp. $K_\text{b}$ that can be for practical purposes considered as infinite, with zero values for the respective conjugate bases/acids.
E.g. hydrochloric acid is a strong acid (i.e. stronger than $\ce{H+(aq)}$), therefore chloride ion is so weak base it is usually not considered as one.
All pairs wit value neither being effectively infinity nor zero are conjugate pairs of a weak acid and a weak base.
E.g. an acid with $\text{p}K_\text{a}=3$ is weak.
But it's conjugate base with $\text{p}K_\text{b}=14-\text{p}K_\text{a}=11$ is weak as well, even much weaker.
So better is rather to say:

If an acid/base is weak, its conjugate base/acid is weak too.
If a weak acid/base is stronger than other weak acid/base, the conjugate base/acid of the former is weaker weak base/acid than the conjugate base/acid of the latter.
If an acid/base is strong, its conjugate base/acid is so weak it is usually not even considered as a base/acid.


Lets get terms straight. Acids 1. donate protons or 2. accept electron pairs. This means that in the process the acid molecule either becomes a negative ion or becomes less positive by one +charge. Ponder this until you understand; it may take minutes, hours, days, months, or years because there are many nuances.
$\ce{HA}$ + $\ce{:B}$ = $\ce{:A}^{-}$ + $\ce{HB}^{+}$. $\ce{HA}$ is an acid, $\ce{:A}^{-}$ is what remains of the molecule after the proton is transferred. Notice it has one less +charge and has an electron pair. This means it is a base. It is the conjugate base of the acid. The reaction can be reversed as is or the conjugate base can be reacted with another acid.
Acids are generally characterized by their reactions with water although they also have properties in other materials. Water from self-ionization has two resident acids: $\ce{2H_2O}$ = $\ce{H_3O}^{+}$ + :$\ce{OH}^{-}$. The acids are the $\ce{H_2O}$ molecules and a small concentration of hydrated hydronium ions, $\ce{H_3O}^{+}$. Water also has two resident bases again $\ce{H_2O}$: molecules and small amounts of $\ce{OH}^{-}$.  They all are in equilibrium.
The strongest acid in reasonably dilute solutions[say<1M] is $\ce{H_3O}^{+}$.  An acid stronger than $\ce{H_3O}^{+}$ reacts with water almost completely to form $\ce{H_3O}^{+}$. These are the common strong acids: nitric, sulfuric, hydrochloric, etc.. These acids are effectively 100% ionized in water. This means that their conjugate bases are weaker bases than water molecules; this makes them relatively unreactive in water solution. Weak acids are weaker than $\ce{H_3O}^{+}$ but stronger than $\ce{H_2O}$. They range from reasonably strong: phosphoric, hydrogen sulfate, $\ce{Al[H_2O]_6}^{3+}$, citric; to moderately strong: acetic, ammonium ion; to very weak: hydrocyanic, $\ce{HCN}$. The conjugate bases of weak acids are stronger as the acid is weaker. The bases are stronger bases than water but weaker bases than hydroxide ion. Acids with the same strength as water, such as alcohols, some carbonyl compounds, neutral salts, exist in equilibrium with water. Weaker acids such as ammonia, acetone, acetylene do not ionize in water; their bases react to give hydroxide ion and the conjugate acid. These bases cover a wide range from the enolate ion of acetone to the very basic methylmagnesium Grignard reagent or sodium hydride.
Write out equations for each class of acids using real compounds with the realization that each is an equilibrium reaction.
